# Grid item doesn't respect dot notation in grid-template-areas

Tags: css, css-grid

According to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for *grid-template-areas*, if I specify a dot for a column, the space won't be occupied.

According to [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/0pfxLevt/), it's getting the item C in the place of the dot.

```css
div.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 30% 10% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: "text text . button" "check span . button";
}

div.outer > div.texty { grid-area: text; }

div.outer > div.checky { grid-area: check; }

div.outer > span { grid-area: span; }

div.outer > div.butty { grid-area: button; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="texty">A</div>
  <div class="checky">B</div>
  <span class="showy">C</span>
  <div class="butty">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with using the word `span` as your grid-area name. The word span is used when spanning multiple gridlines, and thus will confuse the css parser.

```
div.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 30% 10% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "text text . button"
    "check show . button";
}

div.outer>span { grid-area: show; }
```

Edit 1:
To add on, the reason why the span initially took up the space of the first dot(.) is because the `span.showy`'s `grid-area: span;` was not recognized and thus it did not have a place on the grid. In this case, it will take up the first available space, which is the first dot(.). There is nothing wrong with the dot notation at all.

Edit 2:
An example of span usage in `grid-area`, taken from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp)
Make "item1" start on row 2 column 1, and span 2 rows and 3 columns:

```
.item1 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 2 / span 3;
}
```

Comment: I sensed it was something stupid... While the issue is resolved and answer accepted, I wonder if you can elaborate on the details of what *span* will be interpreted as in the context of *grid-area* and string declaring an area of the template. I understand de facto that there was a collision and I'm not contradicting that statement. I just fail to realize in what way it collided.

Comment: Hahaha, you were writing the elaboration while I was writing the request for it. And you posted yours three seconds before I asked. Impressive!

Comment: Oh but what I elaborated on was not what you're actually asking. Just a coincidence in timing, haha. I've found an example and edited the answer, to answer your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769254/3597276), the problem is using the name "span" as the `grid-area` value.

When you define your own name for `grid-area`, you're using what the spec calls a [**`<custom-ident>`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement) (custom identifier). Pre-defined keywords in Grid (such as "span") and CSS-wide keywords (such as "inherit") are not valid custom identifiers.

> [§ 3.2. Author-defined Identifiers: the `<custom-ident>`
>   type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#custom-idents)
>
> Some properties accept arbitrary author-defined identifiers as a
>   component value. This generic data type is denoted by
>   `<custom-ident>`, and represents any valid CSS identifier that would
>   not be misinterpreted as a pre-defined keyword in that property’s
>   value definition. Such identifiers are fully case-sensitive, even in
>   the ASCII range (e.g. "example" and "EXAMPLE" are two different, unrelated
>   user-defined identifiers).
>
> The CSS-wide keywords are not valid `<custom-ident>`s. The default
>   keyword is reserved and is also not a valid `<custom-ident>`.
>   Specifications using `<custom-ident>` must specify clearly what other
>   keywords are excluded from `<custom-ident>`, if any—for example by
>   saying that any pre-defined keywords in that property’s value
>   definition are excluded. Excluded keywords are excluded in all ASCII
>   case permutations.
>
> Note: When designing grammars with `<custom-ident>`, the `<custom-ident>`
>   should always be "positionally unambiguous", so that it’s impossible
>   to conflict with any keyword values in the property.